# cannot update dataset for AutoCompliteTextView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, autocompletetextview

I want to fill my AutoComplete textView with data from web. Howevere, despite asynctask returns me the correct data, autocompletetextview is not updated. Can you help me to fix this problem?
Activity

```
public class FirstTab extends Activity implements OnClickListener,GetStreetNamesInterface{

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterStreenNames;
    private List<String> streetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private AutoCompleteTextView userInput;
 userInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) promptsView
                            .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                    adapterStreenNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FirstTab.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, streetList);
                    userInput.setAdapter(adapterStreenNames);
                    userInput
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                        View view, int position, long id) {
                                    UILApplication.street = userInput.getText()
                                            .toString();
                                }
                            });
                    userInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {         
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                            GetStreetNames task = new GetStreetNames(FirstTab.this);
                            task.execute(s.toString());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {                

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        }
                    });

@Override
    public void onGetStreetNamesInterface(List<String> result) {
        if(result!=null && result.size()>0){
            streetList.clear();
            streetList.addAll(result);
            adapterStreenNames.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("streets","updated");
            for(String s:streetList){
                Log.d("streets",s);
            }
        }


    }
```

AsyncTask

```
public class GetStreetNames extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    private GetStreetNamesInterface callback;
    public GetStreetNames(GetStreetNamesInterface callback){
        this.callback=callback;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        UserFunctions u = new UserFunctions();
        return u.getStreetName(params[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(result!=null && result.length()>0){
            String[] parts = result.split("\n");
            for (int i=0; i<parts.length;i+=2){
                String[] element = parts[i].split("\\|");
                options.add(element[1]);

            }
            callback.onGetStreetNamesInterface(options);
        }
        else{
            callback.onGetStreetNamesInterface(null);
        }
    }


}
```

interface

```
public interface GetStreetNamesInterface {
    public void onGetStreetNamesInterface(List<String> result);
}
```

Comment: update your adapter dataset, once you got the values. i.e in onPostExecute

Comment: is is done in`onGetStreetNamesInterface`

Comment: thats fine but where you are updating adapter.notifyDatasetChanged().

Comment: just above it streetList.clear();
            streetList.addAll(result);

Comment: Ok, and are you getting this `Log.d("streets","updated");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your method as:-

```
public void onGetStreetNamesInterface(List<String> result) {
        if(result!=null && result.size()>0){
            streetList.clear();
            streetList.addAll(result);
            //adapterStreenNames.notifyDataSetChanged();
 adapterStreenNames = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FirstTab.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, streetList);

            userInput.setAdapter(adapterStreenNames);
            Log.d("streets","updated");
            for(String s:streetList){
                Log.d("streets",s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes, also log street shows desiered data. Thats why i am so confused:)

Comment: can you please try on it.

Comment: now it works, but i dont understand why it is nessesary to rebuild adapter. For all views( witch requires adapters) it was enough to change list and call notifydatasetchanged();